# Alternative proof of Fundamental Lemma of Variational Calculus?

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, alternative-proof

I am confused by one of the proof in the *Calculus of Variations* by Gelfand and Fomin. On page 9, we have

> *Lemma:* If $\alpha(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, and if $\int_a^b \alpha(x)h(x)=0$ for every $h(x) \in \mathcal{C}([a,b])$ such that $h(a)=h(b)=0$, then $\alpha(x)=0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

First, I don't understand why do we need $h(a)=h(b)=0$. Second, the proof in the book and in many other resources used contradiction. But can we simply argue that since $\mathcal{C}([a,b]) \subset L^2([a,b])$, and in $L^2([a,b])$ we can define the inner product

$$\langle \alpha(x), h(x) \rangle := \int_a^b\alpha(x)h(x) dx$$,

then the result would follow immediately, since $\langle u,v\rangle = 0 \forall v\Longrightarrow u=0$?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can drop the assumption $h(a)=h(b)=0$ but then your assumptions are unnecessary strong.

EDIT:
For the second part: sure, you can use the $L^2$ inner product. But the proving that this bilinear form is non-degenerate is the same thing as to prove your claim, so this is like cheating. Furthermore, you need a little argument, to show that continuous maps that are almost everywhere zero are in fact identically zero (as the $L^2$ inner product is just giving you a statement about equalities almost everywhere).

Comment: Sorry but I don't get the last part. I am restricting myself to the space $\mathcal{C}([a,b])$ with the inner product defined in terms of the integral. Why is that an even stronger assumption?

Comment: I thought you wanted to use the Riesz representation theorem (as you wrote $\langle u, v \rangle = 0 \ \forall v \dots$), but you only use $\Vert u \Vert^2= \langle u, u \rangle =0$ and the fact that it is a norm. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: In order to state that $\forall v \in C([a,b]) \ \langle u,v\rangle = 0$ implies $u = 0 \ a.e.$ you have to use the fact that $C([a,b])$ is dense in $L^2([a,b])$, and this is not an easy task. Without the density assumption the claim is not true in infinite dimensional spaces

Comment: @EmarJ I don't think you need density. You just use the fact that $\Vert u \Vert_{L^2} = 0$ implies $u=0$ a.e. and $\Vert u \Vert_{L^2} = \langle u, u \rangle =0$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven How do you intend to use those result to prove that $\forall v \in C([a,b]) \ \langle u,v \rangle = 0$ implies $u = 0 a.e.$?

Comment: Because in our case $u\in C([a,b])$.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments the point 4 is not really necessary for this form of the lemma. That result is used to prove stronger form of the lemma, for example when $\alpha$ is not continuous.
I leave here my answer:

I suppose these facts are known:

1. $L^2([a,b])$ is an Hilbert space with the usual inner product
2. $u=\mathbf{0}$ in $L^2([a,b])$ means $u = 0 \ a.e.$ (this is because $L^p$ space are quotient spaces)
3. Given a *dense* subset $S$ of an Hilbert space $X$ we have: $$\forall
           v \in S, \ \langle u,v \rangle = 0 \implies u = \mathbf{0}$$

You can now prove the lemma (without the assumption that the function vanish on the boundary) in this way:

$C([a,b])$ is a *dense* subspace of $L^2([a,b])$, so by point 4,  $$h \in C([a,b]), \ \langle \alpha,h \rangle = \int_a^b \alpha(x)h(x)dx = 0 \implies \alpha = \mathbf{0}$$
So $\alpha = \mathbf{0}$ in $L^2$ and hence, using point 2, $\alpha = 0 \ a.e.$

And this proves the lemma without the assumption that $\alpha$ is continuous.

Comment: Point 4 is not needed, as $ \Vert \alpha \Vert_{L^2}=\langle \alpha, \alpha \rangle_{L^2}^{1/2}=0$. This implies $\alpha=0$ in $L^2$ (follows from the fact that $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{L^2}$ is a norm on $L^2$) and thus $\alpha=0$ a.e.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven From what you get $\|\alpha\|_{L^2} = 0$? Taking $h = \alpha$? This works in this very special case

Comment: Of course this works only in this case (respectively it works always, when the element you're interested in belongs to the set S). This is like arguing that the equation $x-5=0$ has a solution in $\mathbb{C}$ by the fundamental theorem of algebra. It's not wrong, but not the best way to do it.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven This proof works also if we didn't require $\alpha$ be continuous. In this special case, anyway, I agree is a little overwhelming.

Comment: I agree, if we drop the continuity assumption (and if we want to prove $\alpha=0$ a.e.) then we need to proceed like you proposed. I mainly disagreed, as you stress the in the final paragraph the importance of point 4 in the alternative proof of the fundamental lemma.

Answer (score 0):

Given $f$ is measurable and locally integrable

$$\int_a^bf(x)h(x) dx=0$$, for all compactly supported smooth functions $h$ with $h(a)=h(b)=0$, then $f=0$ almost everywhere on $[a,b]$

proof :

$r(x)=-{\frac {1}{x^2-a^2}}$

$q(x)=-{\frac {1}{b^2-x^2}}$

$$\psi(x) =e^{q(x)+r(x)} , \text{if $a< x< b$ }$$

$$\psi(x) =0  , \text{if $x$ $\notin (a,b)$}$$

let $u_\sigma(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2 }}e-^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2 }}$

$$g_{\sigma}(x)=\int_a^b \psi(y)f(y)u_{\sigma}(x-y)dy$$

we can identify $h(y)=\psi(y)u_{\sigma}(x-y)$

$h(a)=h(b)=0$

it is known that $$\lim_{\sigma \to 0}g_{\sigma}(x)=f(x)\psi(x)$$ almost everywhere on $[a,b]$

but $g_{\sigma}(x)=0$ implying $f(x)=0$ almost everywhere on $(a,b)$ since $\psi(x)>0$ on $(a,b)$